# Receiving data from elm327 device

Tags: windows-phone-8, bluetooth, elm327

I want to receive data from elm327 device. 
in line 7 I receive `AT+BRSF=24\r` string instead of string with the speed.

```
1.private async Task<string> GetSpeed()
2.    {
3.        string retVal;
4.        _dataWriter.WriteString("010D\r"); // send pid for speed information
5.        await _dataWriter.FlushAsync(); 
6.        await _dataReader.LoadAsync(30);  // get answer
7.       String Message = _dataReader.ReadString(11);
8.        retVal = Message;
9.        if (retVal.Contains('<'))
10.        {
11.        retVal.Substring(0, retVal.IndexOf("<"));

12.        }
13.        return retVal.Replace("\n", "");
14.    }
```

I'm using SDP Bluetooth protocol:

```
PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:SDP"] = "{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with the connecting channel,
I first tried with the next line:

```
_stream = await socket.ConnectAsync(selectedDevice.HostName,"1");
```

but the working channel is 16 and not 1, and the working line is:

```
_stream = await socket.ConnectAsync(selectedDevice.HostName,"16"):
```